# Was Jethro the father in-law of Moses a descendant of abraham?

Tags: genesis, exodus

Genesis 25:1-2 (NKJV)

> 1 Abraham again took a wife, and her name  was  Keturah. 2 And she bore him Zimran, Jokshan, Medan,  **Midian**, Ishbak, and Shuah. 3 Jokshan begot Sheba and  Dedan. And the sons of Dedan were Asshurim, Letushim,  and Leummim. 4 And the sons of Midian  were Ephah,  Epher, Hanoch, Abidah, and Eldaah. All these were the  children of Keturah.

Exodus 2:16-22 (NKJV)

> 16 Now the priest of **Midian** had seven daughters. And  they came and drew water, and they filled the troughs to  water their father’s flock. 17 Then the shepherds came and  drove them away; but Moses stood up and helped them,  and watered their flock.  18 When they came to Reuel their father, he said, “How  is  it that you have come so soon today?”  19 And they said, “An Egyptian delivered us from the hand  of the shepherds, and he also drew enough water for us and  watered the flock.”  20 So he said to his daughters, “And where  is he? Why   is it  that you have left the man? Call him, that he may eat  bread.”  21 Then Moses was content to live with the man, and he  gave Zipporah his daughter to Moses..

Could Jethro have been a descendant of Abraham & keturah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jethro was descended from Abraham but Isaac was Abraham's only begotten son.

Hagar bore Ishmael to Abram, not Abraham.

> Ge 16:16 And Abram [was] fourscore and six years old, when Hagar bare
>   Ishmael to Abram.

Keturah bore Midian.

> Ge 25:2 And she bare him Zimran, and Jokshan, and Medan, and Midian,
>   and Ishbak, and Shuah.

Abrhaham begat Issac

> Ge 25:19 ¶ And these [are] the generations of Isaac, Abraham’s son:
>   Abraham begat Isaac:

This is how Issac is the only begotten son.

The children of Abraham are described as dust, sand by the sea and stars in the firmament. These relate to his children without the word (such as Midian and Jethro), Israel washed by the word, and the saved who are the light of the world in the firmament (Christ).